# Error NU1107 Version conflict detected for Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package, asp.net-core-2.1

After upgrading a test project from .NET Core 2.0 to 2.1 I started getting the following error on build:

```
Error       Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'Api.Tests'.

Error   NU1107  Version conflict detected for Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common. Install/reference Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common 2.8.2 directly to project Api.Tests to resolve this issue. 
    Api.Tests -> Api -> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common (>= 2.8.2) 
    Api.Tests -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 2.0.3 -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization 2.0.3 -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor 2.0.3 -> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp 2.3.1 -> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common (= 2.3.1).   Api.Tests

Error   NU1107  Version conflict detected for Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common. Install/reference Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common 2.8.2 directly to project Api.Tests to resolve this issue. 
    Api.Tests -> Api -> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common (>= 2.8.2) 
    Api.Tests -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 2.2.0-preview3-35497 -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization 2.2.0-preview3-35497 -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor 2.2.0-preview3-35497 -> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp 2.8.0 -> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common (= 2.8.0).  Api.Tests
```

I tried installing Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common 2.8.2 directly in the project but it gave the following error:

```
Restoring packages for Api.Tests.csproj...
NU1608: Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp 2.3.1 requires Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common (= 2.3.1) but version Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common 2.8.2 was resolved.
NU1608: Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.Common 2.3.1 requires Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common (= 2.3.1) but version Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common 2.8.2 was resolved.
Install-Package : NU1605: Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc from 2.2.0-preview3-35497 to 2.0.3. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
Api.Tests -> Services -> CommStack.Conference.Web.Api.Client 1.0.0-CI-20181128-112729 -> CommStack.Web.Api.Client.Common 1.0.0-CI-20181128-112729 -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc (>= 2.2.0-preview3-35497) 
Api.Tests -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc (>= 2.0.3)
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common -Version 2.8.2
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'Api.Tests'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common -Version 2.8.2
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

To solve this issue you have to explicitly install either

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.*" />
```

or

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.1.*" />
```

to your test project depending on a package you use in your API project.